# Set offset for BitmapDrawable while repeating in the x and y direction?

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap, bitmapdrawable

I'm making a 2D platformer game. I have created a texture for the platform, that is meant to be repeated over and over to fill the entire platform, without going over. My first attempt was to draw all the pixels from the bitmap manually, but this caused the background to flicker through while moving the platform (the movement and drawing threads are seperate, so the movement can run at a specific speed, while the FPS doesn't need to suffer). I found this technique worked better:

```
// Init
bitmap = new BitmapDrawable(res, Texture.PLATFORM.getBitmap());
bitmap.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

// Drawing loop
int x = getX() + (isStill() ? 0 : (int)MainActivity.offsetX);
int y = getY() + (isStill() ? 0 : (int)MainActivity.offsetY);

bitmap.setBounds(x, y, x + getWidth(), y + getHeight());
bitmap.draw(canvas);
```

However, the bitmap appears to be staying static while the platform is acting as a "view hole" to see through to the bitmap. The only work around I can think of is to somehow "offset" the static bitmap:

```
bitmap.offset(x, y);
```

Obviously, that isn't a function. I couldn't find one that would do what I want when looking through the docs.

To summon things up, the BitmapDrawable is causing the background to not move with the platform, making it look super weird.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think at those places where you need `bitmap.offset(x, y);`, you need to call `bitmap.setBounds(x, y, x+getWidth(), y+getHeight());`, because that's the only way you can change the location of that `BitmapDrawable`

Comment: @cgb_pandey I am calling the setBounds function, but this just moves where you are looking at the bitmap. Think of it this way: there is a bitmap on a screen you are looking at, and you are then using your hands to only look at one spot. The .setBounds sets where your hands are, not where the bitmap is.

Comment: Sorry, but I am finding it difficult to visualize the scenario. Can you record the screen and send here ?

Comment: @cgb_pandey Here is the link: https://youtu.be/H5bcCvdqNt4

Comment: It looks like the pink-shirted guy is static with respect to the blue background. Only, the brick or wall is moving. So now, you want to move the guy with a sample method like `bitmap.offset(x,y)`, meanwhile the background will be static ?
Can you post more of your code by editing the question?

Comment: @cgb_pandey The character is supposed to remain the in center of the screen, while everything is moving around it. That is what the MainActivity.offsetX & Y are about. Take a close look at the platform. Notice how as the platform moves to the left, the texture on it remains still? It is supposed to look like it is moving; the brick texture should stay in the same place relative to the platform. You could take this as far as saying the platform is moving, and the player is on top of it (but not moving with it). Having the player in the center is to allow for levels larger than the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try these tips in your code:(I assumed the game moves forward in the horizontal direction)

1. The GUY **should only** move up and down(with the appropriate touch input) and **not forward and backward** as you want the focus(or camera alternatively) solely on the GUY.I noticed that the WALL was moving up in your video when the GUY moved from initial higher position of the wall to little bit lower position later, rectify this because the GUY should move down(try to implement Gravity effect).
2. The WALL **should only** move forward(mostly) and backward(less often I guess).The WALL **shouldn't move up and down normally.** Do not apply Gravity effect to it. You can create at least 2 `BitmapDrawable` instance of WALL for a screen. They are going to be reused sequencially(for eg: If the 1st one goes totally outside of the screen, reshow it in the desired position using `setBounds()` method) and continue same for others the whole game.
3. The currently BLUE BACKGROUND, if it is a part of a larger map, then it needs to be appropriately offsetted.
4. One of the obstacles that I can think of at the time of writing this is to **move the WALL down** until it goes out of the screen which results in the death of the GUY.
5. At those places, where I have used the word **move**, you need to use the `setBounds(a, b, c, d)` method to make necessary position based changes as I didn't find other way to update the position of a `BitmapDrawable` instance. I think, you need to use game framework like libGdx to get method of luxury like `setOffset(x, y)` or of similar sort.

Sorry that I could only present you the ideas without specific code as I do not have past experience working in a project like this. Hope, it helps you in anyway possible.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! Here is a good example of what I am trying to do in a scratch game (so it is kind of buggy). https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/156224810 Notice how you need to move both ways to complete the levels (other than the first), and the player stays in the middle. The main difference is that the platforms have a texture, and I am making it in java. The .setBounds is not actually moving the platform texture with the platform, and I am looking for a work around. I don't necessarily need to even use BitmapDrawable.

Comment: Just as a follow up, were you able to look at the scratch project?

Comment: Yeah, I saw the scratch project. It was kind of buggy but was working. In that game, the game moves forward in every direction. Sometimes up other time down and left and right. I think the base on which the GUY stands is static and there is something like `camera` which shows the current screen of focus that is moving along the `GUY`.

Comment: That is the idea, yah. I'm not worried about the what moves where currently, since the platform movement is so odd. I'm just trying to get the textures to line up.

Comment: You can try posting more of your code specifically code related to the problem so that others who have good knowledge in this can help.

Comment: The code in the question is the only relevant part. It is how I am drawing the platform is the issue. You see how when the platform moves, the texture stays static, right? I'm trying to get the little bricks in the texture to move with the platform.

Comment: Probably there is problem with `isStill()` method or `MainActivity.x` and `MainActivity.y` is not updated as expected.

Comment: The ```isStill``` method is for whether or not the x and y is effected by the MainActivity.x and y variables. I know all that stuff is working, as the outline and edges of the platform are moving. The ```isStill``` function isn't within the ```BitmapDrawabe```, so it shouldn't effect it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215352/discussion-between-cgb-pandey-and-mega12345mega).